# Using external cache for mySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to add external cache provider like ehCache or memcache to the mySQL database. By doing this I am hoping that the performance of the mySQL can be improved. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not "add to MySQL" per se as far as I know. You can easily use Memcache(d) for instance in your *system* if you want: not to be rude about it, but basically just 'use' it.

**Now**:
You have code that requests data from your database.

**With Memcache**:
You have code that checks if the data is in the cache. If it isn't, request it from the database and add it to the cache, then return.

In this case you didn't add it to MySQL itself, but it does help you get better results (if you do it right ofcourse). For sql cache you have the query-cache from the database itself, but that only works for especially-equal (that's a strange term) queries.